# decltype causes is_same<T, T> to fail (same type)

Tags: c++, templates, rtti, type-traits, decltype

In the following snippet, I can cause is_same to claim that two types are distinct, even though they have the same mangled name, and this works in both GCC and clang. This only happens when I use decltype, if I use the commented out line then the compiler thinks both types are the same as expected. Is this somehow expected standard conforming behavior, or is this a bug?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T, typename X>
void show(T, X)
{
    auto same = std::is_same<typename T::bar, X>::value;
    std::cout << "They are " << (same ? "the same" : "NOT the same") << std::endl;

    // the same string is always printed both times
    std::cout << typeid(typename T::bar).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(X).name() << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    static constexpr struct E {} nested {};
    using bar = decltype(nested); // They are NOT the same
 //   using bar = E; // They are the same
};

int main()
{
    Foo<int> x;
    show(x, x.nested);
}
```

[Click here to compile for yourself.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed0263971e16fe4b)

Comment: `nested` is implicitly `const` because of the `constexpr`. This is ignored by `typeid`, which drops top-level cv-qualification. But it is not ignored by `is_same`. That is `is_same<int, int const>::value == false`.

Comment: say as an answer and I will mark correct ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `Foo::nested` is `constexpr`, it is implicitly `const`. Therefore the type of `Foo::nested` is `const E`. But when `x.nested` is passed to `show`, the type decays and loses its `const` qualification. Consequently `X` is `E` but `T::bar` is `const E`.

See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1077cd1df2790423

This also explains why `using bar = E;` gives a different result.

Comment: shouldn't const have to be part of the mangled name, since functions can be overloaded on whether their parameters are const?

Comment: @JosephGarvin In what context?

Comment: @JosephGarvin `const` can in general be part of a mangled type name.  But as dyp pointed out, `typeid` strips const: 5.2.8/6 "If the type of the expression or _type-id_ is a cv-qualified type, the result of the `typeid` expression refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the cv-unqualified type."